# Regex to change text between tags

Tags: javascript, regex, text, replace

I have text that I want to remove and replace.  I've have two tags which it lies between:

```
<!--start--></span>
</p>
<p id="nameIs" style="font-size: 12pt;">Dear Mr Johnstone,</p>
<p style="font-size: 12pt;">400 Isle Road</p>
<p style="font-size: 12pt;">Here Road</p>
<p style="font-size: 12pt;">KP33 7OL</p>
<p><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><!--end-->
```

I wan to to replace the text but I can't make the regex work.  It seems not to find the text:

```
var textholder2 = textholder.replace(/<!--start-->.*<!--end-->/, idToUseIs)
```

idToUseIs is the replacement text.

thanks

Comment: It's almost certainly the newlines. It helps if you indicate what language you are running this regexp in.

Comment: It's not a duplicate since I can't interogate the dom it's a text string that I've pulled from and editor that I change and then put back into the editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
textholder.replace(/<!--start-->(.|\n|\r)+<!--end-->/g, idToUseIs)
```

Answer (score 1):

**You dont need regex for fixed string**.

Just use `substring` and simple *maths*.

```
var tok1 = "<!--start-->"
var tok2 = "<!--end-->"
textholder2 = textholder2.substring(0, s.indexOf(tok1)) + 
              textholder2.substring(textholder2.indexOf(tok2)+tok2.length
```